# Pyinstaller doesnt package cv2 in jetson

Tags: pyinstaller, opencv, nvidia-jetson, python

I have a software which I packaged in x86 processors using pyinstaller and it packages all libraries including cv2, however, when I try to package the same software in Jetson TX2, it doesn't package cv2 and throws error on executing the binary file:

```
OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']
```

The reason is cv2 comes preinstalled in TX2 at a different location (`/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages`). However, rest of the libraries which we self-installed are in (`/home/mnauf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`) and maybe this is why pyinstaller fails to package it.

The pyinstaller tries to find cv2 at `/home/mnauf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` and doesn't find there and correspondingly doesn't package, however cv2 imports fine if you do it with python. The reason why cv2 works fine with python is that I suppose python first tries to find a library in `/home/mnauf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` and if unsuccessful, finds in `/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages`.

To solve the packaging problem, I tried the following methodologies and the errors discussed below all come when executing the binary file and don't come at the time of packaging:

1. Copying cv2 from `/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages` to `/home/mnauf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`. It gives:

`ImportError: ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation.`

2. I try to copy cv2 directory from `/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages` to `dist/main` folder created by pyinstaller after packaging but I get the same Import error.
3. Adding the cv2 directory path as a data file in `main.spec` also only copies the folder to `dist/main` and hence gives the same Import error.
4. Adding the `cv2.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so` path only as a data file in main.spec gives `Opencv loader` error.
5. Adding the cv2 directory as a binary file path in main.spec gives the `Import error`.
6. Adding the `cv2.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so` path only as a binary file in main.spec gives the `Opencv loader` error.

Please help me with packing cv2. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied `/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6/cv2.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so` to `/home/mnauf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` and then imported cv2 from python and checked its location where is it importing from by doing this:

```
import cv2
cv2.__file__
```

and it returned me the path I wanted i.e `/home/mnauf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`. Once confident that cv2 is indeed using the directory I want, I ran pyinstaller and  did package the cv2 dependency.

Previously, I had copied the entire folder before creating its executables. This time I only copied the `.so` file, before creating executables and it worked.

And I think "**before creating executables**" is also the trick. You can't just copy the `.so` file to `dist/main` and expect it to work. Also, we concluded that giving `.so` file path as `data file` or `binary file` in `main.spec` doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly. :)